# Redirect without www plus add trailing slash?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^www.mysite.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.[^./]+$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ mysite.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

I am trying to get it to redirect all URLs with no www and also add a trailing slash at the end of a URL at all times.

This is working if you hit it directly without the www, but if you try it with the www it fails and does not remove it nor add the trailing slash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a single rule to remove `www` and add trailing slash:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ http://%1/$1/ [R=301,L,NE]
```

This also avoids hardcoding your domain name in the rule.

Answer (score 1):

You can use these two rules to enforce all the time. Plus you have syntax error in your first condition. It should be `HTTP_HOST` not `REQUEST_URI`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Thanks, but if you hit the site with www it still loads it with www and doesn't remove it.

Comment: @CodingGuru with or without a trailing slash?

Comment: With the trailing slash at the end.